# Submitting a job WITHOUT a queue manager in remote workstations

Tags: linux, unix, job-scheduling, hpc, pbs

Situation:
I have access to 3 remote servers. A job takes a day or more to finish in a sever. I want to start another job automatically after the earlier job finishes. I am not an admin on these remote machines.

Is there a way to know when a job finishes (or when the cpu load decreases below a threshold) and then run the next job (which may be running a some shell script in a particular directory)?

Ultimately, a system similar to PBS or SLURM (not so robust thought).

Is it doable?

Answer (score 2):

use the `batch` command which is widely available on most unix / linux

from man page

```
batch          executes commands when system  load  levels  permit;  in  other
               words,  when  the  load  average  drops below 0.8, or the value
               specified in the invocation of atd.
```

To set the level at which the load average reaches the point when a new batch execution will start pass a -l option to atd.  From man page

> OPTIONS
>          -l      Specifies  a limiting load factor, over which batch jobs should
>                  not be run, instead of the compile-time choice of 1.5.  For  an
>                  SMP  system  with  n  CPUs,  you will probably want to set this
>                  higher than n-1.

So on a system with 4 cpus if the load average is 3.5 there are enough things running to keep 3 and a half cpus busy.

If your job  can use 2 cpus at a time then you'd probably want to set -l to be 1.9 on a 4 cpu system

Comment: It seems batch only works when load is less than 0.8 (is it in fractional units equalling 80%?). So I came across the atd commandto specify the load average? Do you know the syntax of it?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). It can schedule jobs ([limiting the number of simultaneous jobs](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#Number-of-simultaneous-jobs)) [on remote machines through SSH](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#Remote-execution), and even [handles transfer of input data and output results](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#Transferring-files).

Assuming your software is named `a.out` and it takes a parameter which you need to sweep from 1 to 10, you can run a command like the following:

```
parallel -S server1,server2,server3 -j3 ./a.out ::: {1..10}
```

Then, automatically, tasks will be dispatched to the three servers, assigning the next one automatically when one of the current one finishes.